# The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, gulp

I have a CI process setup using Azure DevOps with Self-Hosted Agent for angularjs based project. All the dependencies like Node.js - 10.22.1, Gulp - 3.9.1 are installed globally on the Build server where the Self-Hosted agent (Azure VM with Windows OS) has been installed.

Post running the CI project, I see the frontend package is not getting created. On analysis I found the error: **The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.**

I checked the PATH variables and found it contains both node and npm entries

Can anyone help me how to fix the issue

Comment: To run gulp on Windows, one has to use `npx gulp` or `npm exec gulp` instead of just `gulp`.

Comment: I usually have a job where I also run npm i, and gulp is part of the package so I dont run into that issue.

Comment: The above setup works without any issues in my local DEV environment and also I tested it with cmd and it works without any issues. It breaks at the build server level only